# How to calculate area around a geometry using postgis?

Tags: oracle, postgresql, postgis

I want to convert the following oracle spatial function into postgis spatial function to calculate an area around a geometry

```
sdo_geom.sdo_area(geometry, 0.005, 'unit=SQ_MILE')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - please tell us what you have tried already, what errors you are getting, and then we can help you

Comment: I am new to postGIS as well as oracle-spatial.I have found ST_Area function in postGIS,how to write the above query in postGIS ?? Also what this 0.005 value indicates?

Comment: I would suggest the product documentation is a very good place to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comment, [ST_Area](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Area.html) may use to calculate the area of a geometry.

Now let's take a look at the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28400/sdo_objgeom.htm#SPATL1110) of Oracle `sdo_area` function. If you already have the geometry object stored in PostGIS you can use that value, otherwise, you need to convert Oracle geometry object to PostGIS geometry object.

Since the geometry object is stored in binary format, you need to use Oracle `Get_WKT` to get the [Well-known text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) representation of the geometry object.